# Are Win32 menu functions thread-safe?

Tags: c, winapi

Is there any information on whether or not the following functions can be called from worker threads that do not run the main UI loop?

EnableMenuItem()
CheckMenuItem()
SetMenu()

I checked MSDN but couldn't find anything...

Thanks!

Comment: I think they are. They work with OS primitives and it should be the responsibility of the OS to make them thread safe. Just like HANLDE type and CRITICAL_SECTION. You use them to make your code thread-safe, so they, themselves, HAVE to be thread-safe

Comment: They are thread-safe, but using them from a background thread can create race conditions in your app. For example, you update a variable then call `SetMenu`. During the race window, your app can get a message for the old menu even though the variable says you have the new menu.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That comment sounds more like an answer to me.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks. Of course I have to be very careful to avoid race conditions but it's good to know that they can be safely called from worker threads.

Comment: Is there a reference on them being thread safe? I suspect they use `PostMessage` in their implementation so they are, but I can't find any good info on it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson If you could crash the window manager, that would be a bad thing. The window manager doesn't need to do a beautiful job, but it can't crash.

Comment: @Ben It is, and has been published at [Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 3: Menus, icons, cursors, and accelerator tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/12/480064.aspx).